# Unital ring with nilpotent element x

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,*)$ be an unital ring and $x$ is in $N(R)$ (nilpotent set). How can I show that $1-x$ and $1+x$ are in the set of invertible elements $U(R)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

What is 
$$(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots + x^{n-1})$$

equal to?

Comment: That's 1 - x^n = 1 but how did you get that equation?

Comment: @RaulM. In high school. It's a generalization of the rule $(1-x)(1+x)=1-x^2$.